# Connect to a VPN with Python Automatically

Tags: python, vpn

I have databases I want to automate some data pulls.

To access the databases I have to connect to separate VPNs.

I have the remote gateway, port, and credentials.

How can I use python to automate the connecting and disconnecting from different VPNs?

Comment: How do you connect and disconnect from the VPNs without Python?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I use a client installed on my laptop. So I have to login each time I want to run a script. I'd really prefer it be automated so I can schedule it without needing to login to each VPN.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to VPN/Proxy connect in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35144685/how-to-vpn-proxy-connect-in-python)

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke it's not

Comment: Perhaps this then? https://stackoverflow.com/q/48754813/1256347
In general, could you please indicate what possible solution routes you've looked into already such that others don't suggest them?

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke The solution you linked looks like it's using a linux system. I'm using a windows machine and using fortinet VPN. If that's useful. I have searched Stack Overflow and a general google search and haven't found a specific answer to this question.

Comment: Those are definitely important details to [edit] into your question. Also please include *what* you've searched for on Google and Stack Overflow and what you found that was not helpful, it helps others understand what direction you're thinking in.